# How to verify Adsense PIN if PIN verification card can't be found on my AdSense homepage?

Tags: adsense

[image: What could I do next if I can't find the PIN verification card on my AdSense homepage?]

What could I do next if I can't find the PIN verification card on my AdSense homepage?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Sign in](http://www.google.com/adsense) to your AdSense account.
2. Click Payments and then Verification check.
3. Click Resend PIN.

[image]

***You can only request a new PIN every 3 weeks***